# Change type of permalinks on TinyMCE link dialogue

Tags: permalinks, tinymce

I recently ran into a problem when inserting text links into post content, and then updating the target post's slug or changing permalink options - the link in the post content won't get updated.

This is only really an issue if you forget where you've put text links to other posts, and so don't update them.

So I hit on the idea of somehow altering the Link dialogue in TinyMCE to use shortlinks instread of inserting the full permalink:

so `example.com/mypage/somepage` would instead be inserted as `example.com?p=123`

This way the content links wouldn't need updating unless you trashed the target post.
Does anyone have an idea on how to acheive this - I was hoping there would be a filter for the page results in the link dialogue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a real problem as wordpress remembers all the addresses the content had during it existence and automatically redirects to the recent one. The code is not 100% fail prof but you will need to work very hard to make it fail.

That is the reason you don't need to update links in your content when you change the permalink structure or the slug. If the redirects bother you then use one of the plugins that can detect that (I use broken links) or an external utility.

Comment: Ah I didn't realise that it took care of that - that's brilliant :) thanks!